# why props show different value in render and componentWillReceiveProps?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-router, react-redux

could you please tell me 
why props show different value in render and componentWillReceiveProps  ? when I click on `button` it call both function **render and componentWillReceiveProps** but it show different value of (this.props.val)  why ?

here is code
https://codesandbox.io/s/g5119XP2Z

```
class App extends Component {
  update(){
    render(<App val={this.props.val + 1 }/>, document.getElementById('root'));

  }

  componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps){
    console.log(nextProps.val);
     console.log("====================");
      console.log(this.props.val,"val");

  }
  render(){
    console.log("render========")
          console.log(this.props.val,"val render");

    return (

  <div style={styles}>
    <button onClick={this.update.bind(this)}>{this.props.val}</button>
    <h2>Start editing to see some magic happen {'\u2728'}</h2>
  </div>
)
```

Comment: `componentWillReceiveProps` runs before the component actually receives those new props, which is what triggers the re-render and changes the value of `this.props.val`. You can look at the [documentation](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/react-component.html#componentwillreceiveprops) for `componentWillReceiveProps` for more information.

Answer (score 1):

As the name suggests, `ComponentWillReceiveProps` triggers whenever any property values is changed and component will receive it in `nextProps` collection. This event thus looks for changed values and update component's props collection with new values. Only after that `render` executes which makes perfect sense.

More details:

https://developmentarc.gitbooks.io/react-indepth/content/life_cycle/update/component_will_receive_props.html